# Star sign in Eclipse code recommender

Tags: eclipse

I did not notice in the previous version of Eclipse but in Eclipse Mars, there is a small yellow star sign left to the recommended thing.

[image]

What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the star and the percentage are added by the Intelligent Code Completion.
Follow this Link for more http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#intelligent-code-completion

These suggestions are based on context and code analysis (data mined) of similar situations. The percentage is presumably an indication for the confidence of that suggestion.

Protected methods are in fact indicated by a yellow diamond with rounded corners, similar to the icon in the outline view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this does not answer my question. I have specifically asked for the meaning of the yellow star-like shape in the code completion dialog.

Comment: It represents "favorite".. that means more likely "most used"

Comment: Then the percentage and the star-like shape says the same thing in different ways.